# Pipeline Syntax for a homegrown custom plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We use an internal Jenkins plugin developed to interact with UrbanCode Deploy for performing auto deployment. Im working on converting the the jobs to use Jenkins Pipeline. How can I write the pipeline syntax for such a custom plugin?